# Selenium C# Web Driver 4.11.0 not working on deployment server

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

We have upgraded selenium C# web driver package from 4.2 to 4.11 version and recently with the new features of selenium 4.6 onwards we don't need to provide selenium driver path as selenium manager is taking care of this.

We have updated selenium C# packages from 4.2 to 4.11 and it is working as expected on my local machine but when we deploy the changes on deployment server and try to run it , we are getting the below error.

error:

> Unable to obtain chrome using Selenium Manager; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location stacktrace   at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverFinder.FullPath(DriverOptions options)     at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(ChromeOptions options)     at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()

```
 var headlessValue = Convert.ToBoolean(_config["Driver:HeadlessFlag"]);
  var downloadDirectory = _config["Driver:BaseDownloadLocation"];
  var currDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
  var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
  chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
  chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
  chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
               
  chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @customPath + @currentUser);
  chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
  chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
  chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);
  ChromeDriverService driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
  var driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, chromeOptions);
  var driverProcessIds = driverService.ProcessId;
  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait.Add(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
  driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad.Add(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
```

Comment: Error says you cannot create the Default Service.  What type OS is the deploy server?  Is it a IIS?  Did you check the event logs in the server to see if there were any errors?  IIS you have very little access to the machines recourses.   In most cases you only have GUEST privilege.  Best to use a shared network drive instead of a driver on the IIS machine.

Comment: Could you please update the question with a code example?

Comment: Code example updated

Comment: @jdweng OS deployed on Server is Windows Server 2019 and IIS is used for hosting. We have checked event logs , we get below error message. Faulting application name: selenium-manager.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x64c7e8dc
Faulting module name: selenium-manager.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x64c7e8dc
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x00180215
Faulting process id: 0x1e40
Faulting application start time: 0x01d9d6508346a529
Faulting application path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iForms\selenium-manager\windows\selenium-manager.exe

Comment: Following had same error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70897698/selenium-unable-to-find-input-elements-inside-iframe-using-switchto

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved, It is due to  Write permission to IIS user group to wwwroot folder. With Selenium 4.6 onward the driver will get downloaded by Selenium Manager and to store the driver.exe file it is required the write permission for our deployed virtual directory.