# Error starting process: /app/selenium-manager/linux/selenium-manager

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, .net-core

I try to use Selenium Manager instead of WebDriverManager package for .Net since it's not beta from Selenium.WebDriver 4.11.0 anymore.
It works fine on my windows local machine and doesn't work on linux

Now I have the following error:

```
Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchDriverException: Unable to obtain chrome using Selenium Manager; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
   ---> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Error starting process: /app/selenium-manager/linux/selenium-manager  --browser "chrome" --output json
   ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (13): An error occurred trying to start process '/app/selenium-manager/linux/selenium-manager' with working directory '/app'. Permission denied
     at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String resolvedFilename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
     at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
     at OpenQA.Selenium.SeleniumManager.RunCommand(String fileName, String arguments)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at OpenQA.Selenium.SeleniumManager.RunCommand(String fileName, String arguments)
     at OpenQA.Selenium.SeleniumManager.DriverPath(DriverOptions options)
     at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverFinder.FullPath(DriverOptions options)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverFinder.FullPath(DriverOptions options)
     at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(ChromeOptions options)
     at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
```

Any ideas how to fix that? I don't do anything special (driver must be installed automatically based on Selenium docs) but it failed when  I try to use it

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
var driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), chromeOptions, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
```

Comment: Looks like other people had similar issues.  It may be the TLS certificate that is not loaded on Linux machine.  See : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11291

Comment: The error is different... I think I have similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76961132/selenium-c-sharp-web-driver-4-11-0-not-working-on-deployment-server?rq=2 but I don't know how to fix it on our server. It would be better to change path from '/app/selenium-manager/linux/selenium-manager' to some project-related path. Is it possible in Selenium Manager? I prefer to use project .bin folder instead of my root system folder /app/...

Comment: I made comments to the link you provided.  The error is due to login credentials being different on two apps.  I would check the Linux log files to see the different in working and non working.

Comment: For now I've just added "RUN chown -R user:user /app" to my dockerfile and it works! However, I don't like it... I don't know why this path is hardcoded by selenium manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I've just added "RUN chown -R user:user /app" line to my .dockerfile and it works. Probably, there is a way to change this path from '/app/selenium-manager/linux/selenium-manager' to some custom path but I can't find it